# Getting value from a select and echoing

Tags: php, html, file, csv

I have built a form that has a select tag, which generates options from a .csv file. But I am having trouble getting the selected option, and then echoing it later in the form.

The variable is called $selectedCurrency.

**EDIT:** I wan't the value to show before posting/submitting the form, and my understanding of using $_POST is therefore wrong.

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="mb-3">Hvilket land eller valuta?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="selectedCurrency" id="selectedCurrency">

          <?php
          $handle = fopen("currency/kurs.csv", "r");
          $g=0;

          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
              $num = count($data);

              if ($g!=0) {
                  ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>">
            <?php echo $data[1]; ?> - <?php echo $data[2]; ?>
          </option>

          <?php
              }
              $g++;
          }
            fclose($handle);

          $selected_val = $_POST['selectedCurrency'];

          ?>

        </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="mb-3">Hvor meget vil du købe?</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Beløb i <?php echo $selected_val ?>">
  </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Edit:** I would like the value to show before submitting the form.

Comment: You're using this: 
$selected_val = $_POST['selectedCurrency'];
then echoing $selectedCurrency;

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... I have corrected it, but the variable still doesn't get echoed, it is just empty without any errors. Thanks for noticing the mistake.

Comment: I see the form tag but I am unable to find submit button. How will "$_POST['selectedCurrency'];" work if the form is not submitted

Comment: There is a submit button in my actual code, but I had to remove it, because the post included too much code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Dude, write javascript/jQuery for "onchange" attribute of your select tag

Answer (score 0):

`while` part of your code should look like this:

```
$selected_val = $_POST['selectedCurrency'];
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
    $num = count($data);

    if ($g!=0) {
    ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>" <?php echo $selected_val == $data[0] ? "selected": "" ?>>
            <?php echo $data[1]; ?> - <?php echo $data[2]; ?>
        </option>

    <?php
    }
    $g++;
}
```

Move your `$selected_val` variable above the while loop so that it will be available under the loop and you can check it against your options value.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still won't output the selected option for some reason... It doesn't give any errors, but it just turns out to be empty.

Comment: Are you sure you are submitting form? because `$_POST['selectedCurrency']` this var will only be available after form is submitted

Comment: I would like the value to show, before submitting the form. Should I remove $_POST ?

Comment: *"I would like the value to show, before submitting the form. Should I remove $_POST ?"* - You need JS for that.

Comment: as @FunkFortyNiner you may need javascript.. but your question is sounding more unclear now.

Comment: My initial understanding was that I could this in PHP that's why my question might be unclear now... but my questions is actually how I get the selected value to display later on in the form.

Comment: @ZakiHussain you need to make up your mind here. Voting to close the question as unclear.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, my question is still "How can I display the selected option later in the form"

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen before submitting the form, you'll have to use Javascript/jQuery for that. In your case:

```
    $("#selectedCurrency").change(function(){
    let scurrency = $("#selectedCurrency").val();
   //add id into input [type="number"] tag, for precise selection targeted input tag."
   //I have used "svalue" as id of input type number
   $('#svalue').val(scurrency);
});
```

Comment: You should look at the edit that was made to the question also.

Comment: Can you specify about which part you're talking about, He edited the Question after I told him about the mismatch of variable

Comment: Why should the OP "do it like this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Rajnish, Sorry but I found out that I was trying to use $_POST wrong, since it would only show the variable after submitting the form. I am trying to display it before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using an onChange attribute on my select tag, and then writing the following function:

```
    <script>

      function getSelectedCurrency(selectObject) {
        var currency = selectObject.value;
        document.getElementById("selectedCurrency").innerHTML = currency;
      }

    </script>
```